# how to write html code inside php?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to write some html code in php. In this html code I am calling a javascript function. but while it is calling the function there is a problem. I think the problem is quotes but I couldn't fix it.

This is the html code that I want to put inside php.

```
<table>
 <tr>
 <a href="javascript:chng('img');"><img src="s.png" name="img"></a> 
 </tr>
</table>
```

and this is my javascript code;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
img1 = "s.png";
img2 = "k.png";
function chng(c_img) {
if (document[c_img].src.indexOf(img1)!= -1) document[c_img].src = img2;
else document[c_img].src = img1;
} 

</script>
```

How can i write this html inside php code?

Thanks

Comment: A table with one row and no cells? A href with a javascript: URI? A link with no text content? An image with no alt text? An image with a name attribute? Globals in JS? Unintelligible abbreviations in function names? document.name_of_element? `if` without `{}`? I think half a dozen puppies just died.

Comment: this code is just sample. this is not my real code. i just wanna learn how to do it. then i will put the answer in my real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could echo the html; eg

```
echo "<table>
 <tr>
 <a href=\"javascript:chng('img');\"><img src=\"s.png\" name=\"img\"></a> 
 </tr>
</table>
";
```

Just escape the double quotes with a backslash.

Comment: thanks it works. but now i have another error.
document[c_img].src is undefined
[Break on this error] if (document[c_img].src.indexOf(img1)!= -1) document[c_img].src = img2; 

it was working before i put the html code inside php. but now it doesnt

Answer (score 9):

```
<?php

// your php code

?>

<table>
 <tr>
 <a href="javascript:chng('img');"><img src="s.png" name="img"></a> 
 </tr>
</table>

<?php

// your php code

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
img1 = "s.png";
img2 = "k.png";
function chng(c_img) {
if (document[c_img].src.indexOf(img1)!= -1) document[c_img].src = img2;
else document[c_img].src = img1;
} 

</script>

<?php
```

Comment: Down vote with pleasure, but make me correct where I am wrong.

Comment: Not my downvote, but this was my first instinct but thought it would be a smart-ass answer. Couldn't think that OP ever meant this from `while it is calling the function there is a problem? i think the problem is about quotation marks but i couldnt fix it.`

Comment: ..but I guess in this context, looking at this code, it's exactly what he needed to know.

Answer (score 2):

you also could wrap your code in heredoc, and echo it afterwards http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP heredoc syntax:

var $js = <<<JS

// code

JS;

Escapes and echo "<html_code>" is a noob style.

Answer (score -1):

Use scriptlets and the command echo.

```
<?
  echo "<script type=\"text\/javascript\">"
?>
```

and so far. But pay attention of masking quotations signs and backslashes, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Write html tags inside php code isn't nice. Read about templates to php as Smarty

http://www.smarty.net/